# Regex to get iTH instance of a match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have:

```
name=joe&company_id=7&name=Barbie
```

and want to get the (in this case) second instance of name. How would I do this? I'd like to expand this functionality to get the iTH instance - is that possible via grouping? If language matters, ideally in JavaScript.

Comment: Which tool/programming language do you use? And where does this string come from? If it's an URL, the second `name` will overwrite the first, so your question is a bit vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern:

```
(?<=name=).*?(?=name=)name=([a-zA-Z]+)
```

```js
var myString = "name=joe&company_id=7&name=Barbie"
var myRegexp = /(?<=name=).*?(?=name=)name=([a-zA-Z]+)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code targets modern version of the browsers, there is no reason to use regex. Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams):

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams("name=joe&company_id=7&name=Barbie");
var name = searchParams.getAll("name").slice(-1)[0];
```

Getting the nth instance is as easy as accessing the array returned by `getAll`

If you have the full URL at earlier point in the code:

```
let searchParams = new URL(url).searchParams;
```